# How to secure api end point in php slim framework

Tags: php, angular, api, slim, secure-coding

I have already created an api using php slim framework. But I have an issue with securing my api. I want to access only api for the authenticated users only.

I have already added user login to my front end angular project. That is fine. But when the someone directly calls the api endpoint its show the result related to that endpoint.

For example. I have the following endpoint.

```
slimapi/customers/view
```

This endpoint shows all the data in the customer's table.

When someone types this URL in the browser. it shows all data related to that api endpoint. but I want to show some customers message when someone tries to access my api endpoint without using front end application.

Answer (score 2):

## You can Manage JWT Token

### when client sends you login request and if login request and credential matched then you give the client a token. Then After every request, you check the token is it valid then you give the access.

just see the documentation of JWT
https://github.com/tuupola/slim-jwt-auth

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [OpenID Connect protocol](https://openid.net/connect/) (based on OAuth 2 and JSON Web Tokens​).

But this would maybe an overkill for the most scenarios, because a JWT would only makes sense if you have to scale the "session" over multiple servers and/or load balancers in the back-end infrastructure. Also a simple logout is not possible with JWT based tokens. If you start to manage JWT blacklists on the server-side, the API will not be stateless anymore.

I think a very long **API-Token** within the HTTP header, e.g. a UUID, would be secure and good enough in the most cases.

The HTTP `Authorization` request header contains the credentials to authenticate a user agent with a server, usually after the server has responded with a `401 Unauthorized` status and the WWW-Authenticate header.

**Syntax:**

```
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

**Basic Auth**

```
Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l
```

**Token based**

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIXVCJ9...TJVA95OrM7E20RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

**UUID as Token**

```
Authorization: Bearer bb79dfb5-17fd-4ebc-acd5-548e308e5f9a
```

Also make sure, that all API request are SSL (HTTPS) encrypted.

PS: If you just want secure your API for a **web application**, a classic `Session` with `Cookies` is also good enough and very secure.